# load() in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have some questions about jQuery and the `load()` function.

I have a form which sends 3 params that are needed for a query. I wanted to load the data to a specified `div` without reloading a page so I tried with `load` function in jQuery. It seems ok but there are some questions that I need to ask.

I made a `div` with id "response" that I will use to load data. I've done something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#response").load(("search.php?param1=1&param2=2&param3=3$search=send"))
});
```

And it works fine. But I have tried to do it in a function

```
function search() {
    $("#response").load(("search.php?param1=1&param2=2&param3=3$search=send"))
}
```

and then use it when dom tree is ready. The query returned what I wanted it to, but on the new page. Well, during writing that I tried using `return false` which should block the page and keep it from reloading (Am I wrong here ?).

When the `return false` statment is in the search function and the function is used

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   search();
})
```

it doesn't work. But when I place a return statement after the `search()` call, it works the way it should. Can someone tell me why?

After that, I was wondering if there is a chance to do the same thing using the `ajax` function in jQuery.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do once the search page loads. Please clarify.

Comment: Display some records from database, always more than one record.

Comment: Why does it need to loaded via AJAX the first time?  Can't you just include the data when the page loads?

Comment: I can't because user has to fill the form to see records that he is interested in.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, and you shouldn't need a return statement. Are you sure there isn't some other detail you're not explaining which could be the cause?

Comment: I dont know, maybe the problem is that I have a file search.php and there is the form Im using to pass params to a file search_plan.php where the query is and where the records from db are returned ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to debug your old code, but I'm going to give you a definite working solution.

```
// jQuery function
(function($) {
    $.fn.return_search = function () {
        $.get('search.php?param1=1&param2=2&param3=3$search=send', function(data) {
            $(this).html(data);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

// Call
$('#response').return_search();
```

This will create a jQuery extension plugin and you can call it on the element, you want it to be returned in.